# Where can I find the nightly build release number?

Tags: qgis

As far as I know every QGIS nightly build has a release number such as 81be559? Where can I find this number?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's right next to the QGIS code revision in my OSGeo4W install. Maybe check where you get, when you click on the "exported" link.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/exported Page not found 404 :/